# HTML5 Video not auto-playing

Tags: mysql, html, html5-video, autoplay

I'm requesting this chunk of html from a mysql database:

```
<p>Hello.<br><video src="video/hi.mp4" width=100% height=100% autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

It displays, but won't autoplay. On a static HTML page it goes off without a hitch.
The request comes from an ajax call for a matching keyword that is being typed into a input bar.

Any ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: Removed MYSQL from title. I believe it is important to give context so I left it in the tags, description.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can imagine is that the browser has not finished loading the page and or not getting a onload(). Can you start the video using a script?

<video id="video" src="video/hi.mp4" autoplay  ></video>

<script>

document.getElementById("video").play();

</script>

Answer (score 0):

Aren't some quotes or attributes missing?

```
<video src="video/hi.mp4" style="width:100%; height=100%;" autoplay="autoplay"></video> ?
```

Comment: No, I don't think so.  from http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html
<video src="pr6.webm" width="320" height="240"></video>

Answer (score 0):

Your web browser doesn't know that the HTML came from an SQL database, so it's not likely that it behaves differently in the two cases. I'm inclined to assume that there is some other problem with the page.

What are the URLs of the static and dynamic pages? Does the relative URL "video/hi.mp4" resolve to the address of your video correctly in both cases?

Comment: The URL's are the same. I understand that the browser isn't biased, but I just thought it might help in determining the cause of the problem.

Comment: Also, the 1st frame of the video displays, so it's finding it no problem.

Comment: I see you're saying the dynamic HTML comes from an AJAX call - so it's inserted into an existing page, it doesn't come from a brand new load of a page?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://pauljacobson.org/2010/01/22/firefox-and-its-limited-html-5-video-support/, Firefox only supports ogg formatted videos.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed mine by using autoPlay instead of autoplay.